# Are there p-adic or finite field analogue of Drinfeld-Jimbo's quantum groups

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

[Drinfeld-Jimbo's quantum groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) are associated algebras over the field of complex numbers. Are there some references about the analogue of Drinfeld-Jimbo's quantum groups over a p-adic field or a finite field. I searched on google but did not find the references. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think Lusztig's book gives a construction over $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this the kind of thing you're looking at, but for the rigid analytic context there's some work of Yan Soibelman that might be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.2890.pdf.

in the same vein, there is the PhD thesis of Christian Wald: https://edoc.hu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/18452/18872/wald.pdf?sequence=1.

And more recently the PhD thesis of Nicolas Dupré: https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/291025/thesis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y, who also has two preprints on this topic:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.05417.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.06177.pdf